# add zeros infront of the value in the text box

Tags: javascript

I have created a demo in jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/345/)

```
function pad (str, max) 
{
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

I have used the above functions to add leading zeros.

In the text box I can enter 3 digits before the colon. I need to enter the values with leading zero. An example is shown in the program itself(Like 'First Part' field in the output). Is there any way to do this?

Also I need 2 digits after the colon. How can I modify the code to enter two digits after the first colon? I only need one colon, no need of furthers colons. Eg: 435:23 or 045:23 or 005:23

Comment: I need to modify my jquery function in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/347/

```
$('#ssn').keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value.replace(/[^:\d]/g, '');
    var parts = val.split(':');
    $( "#f-length" ).html( val.length );
    $( "#f-part" ).html( pad(parts[0],3) );
    $( "#s-part" ).html( pad(parts[1],2) );
    this.value = val;

});

function pad (str, max) {
    if(str === void(0)) { str = ''; }
    return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried your fiddle. But doesn't come up with leading zeros in the text box. Also there is no split with colon. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry Oriol. I need to enter in the text box as my field 'Output should be'. http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/351/  I have changed my fiddle

Comment: @NewPHP Try http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/356/. But it's not very clear to me what exactly you want...

Comment: Thank you for your help Oriol. I mean I need leading zeros in the text box itself.